# What do these values in the freeverb diagram mean?

Tags: audio, algorithms

I am implementing a reverb based on the Freeverb implementation detailed [here.](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/pasp/Freeverb.html#fig:freeverb) There is also a more in-depth description of the LBCF in question [here,](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/pasp/Lowpass_Feedback_Comb_Filter.html#sec:lbcf) but I am not able to find the information I want at that link.

In the diagram given, they use a lowpass-feedback comb-filter, denoted by `LBCF(f,d,N)`. `N` is clearly the number of samples. I suspect `d` means the feedback gain, though I'm not sure if a value of .2 makes sense for that. I have no idea what `f` means.

So here are my questions:

- What does `d` mean?
- What does `f` mean?
- What cutoff frequency is used for the lowpass filters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a Lowpass-Feedback Comb Filter, so let's dissect this one at a time:

1. Comb filter: You have delay line and add the output back to the original signal. That gives you a single echo
2. Feedback: You take some of the output of the delay line and put it back into the input of the delay line. That gives you a series of echo's that repeat regularly. You need to put a gain < 1 on this, otherwise it will repeat forever. That gain is called the feedback gain and controls how fast (or slow) the echoes decay.
3. You put a lowpass into the feedback path to model the typical absorption in a room that's higher at high frequencies and lower at low frequencies. You basically make the feedback gain frequency dependent.

$d$ is the pole location of the lowpass filter. That determines the cutoff frequency of your lowpass filter

$f$ is the feedback gain and determines how quickly the repeating echoes decay. That should be a function of the reverb time (at low frequencies) and the delay size

Comment: How can I get the cutoff frequency from the pole location?

Comment: Depends on how you define it. This is not a "true" lowpass filter since it doesn't have a zero at Nyquist. In general, amplitude goes down with frequency but you won't hit -3dB if $d$ gets too small. A $d$ of 0.2 you'll get a -3dB point of about 15.5kHz @44.1kHz sample rate. For a $d$ of 0.1 there is no -3dB point at all